# Android aar library doesn't contain dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

i saw similar questions, but not found accepted answers.
Problem - i have my own android library with some tiny functions.
My library uses others - f.e. Hawk (no sql database).
My library gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'library.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.orhanobut:hawk:1.23'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Library works fine. And if i use it as project inside another project - it work too. But when i generate `*.aar` file (with `gradle` -> `assembleRelease`) and include into separate project - it fails. Project see ONLY MY library's class. Hawk com.orhanobut.hawk package and ofc others (if i will use then) are not visible. So `ClassNotFoundException` comes.
If i remove

```
minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'library.pro'
```

the result doesnt change.
I tried to add the following line into proguard file (library.pro)

```
-keep class com.orhanobut.hawk {public *;}
-keep class com.orhanobut.hawk.* {public *;}
```

Result is the same.

So i have two question:
1 - what should i do to make my main project see my library's third party dependencies?
2 - is is possible to obfuscate my library's code (only mine, not dependencies)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> what should i do to make my main project see my library's third party dependencies?

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the module.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repository **you have to specify the dependencies also in your project**.

You should use a **maven repository**, private or public, to avoid the issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: Okey, can you provide a help link please?

Comment: @TooLazy Here a post: https://medium.com/prismapp/publishing-android-library-to-bintray-ba588184b690

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve the problem of dependencies is to get the *jar* files of the dependencies you want to use and place them in the libs folder of your module. This will copy all the your dependency *jars* into your library's jar or aar.

Note that I have emphasized jar because you cannot include aar file in libs folder, gradle still doesn't support aar file inside aar out of the box. There are a few gradle plugins like fataar which solve that problem.